# Error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null with srmklive / laravel-paypal v.3

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I'm using the srmklive/laravel-paypal v.3 package ( https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal that does not have documentation) in a laravel project.
when i press a button the controller process this code:

```
public function payment()
{
    $provider = new PayPalClient;

    // Through facade. No need to import namespaces
    $provider = PayPal::setProvider();
    $provider->setCurrency('EUR');
    $provider->createOrder([
        "intent"=> "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units"=> [
            "amount"=> [
              "currency_code"=> "EUR",
              "value"=> "100.00"
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

But i have this error:
**Trying to access array offset on value of type null**

Relative to this portion of code

```
$this->apiUrl = collect([$this->config['api_url'], $this->apiEndPoint])->implode('/');
```

of class srmklive\paypal\src\Traits\PayPalAPI\Orders.php:21

Someone can help me and show how to use this package?

Comment: It would seem $this->config is null, perhaps (maybe the value of what the api_url or the apiEndPoint are set to is null)

Comment: tnx but why? The class srmklive\paypal\src\Traits\PayPalAPI\Orders.php is in the plugin, out of my control. The documentation does not show how to set if, if it's necessary.

Comment: Have you set your config per https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal#configuration

Comment: yes, i've set the config.
In "app_id" how i need to set? where can i get this value?

Comment: You aren't using Adaptive Payments, so no value. You'll just have to debug why things are null at the point you receive that error.